# How Can I get all the contents of this KVP

Tags: c#, .net, keyvaluepair

I am trying to figure out what all is getting passed to the TryAppendDetailSet function. I just want to be sure I am getting everything out of it. Can someone verify that by doing it this way I am not missing anything.

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string[], string[]> kvp in orderedList)
            {
                //i++;
                //j++;
                for(int i =0; i<kvp.Key.Length; i++)
                {
                    for(int j=0;j<kvp.Value.Length;j++)
                    {
                    WriteLogEntry(LOG_ERRORS, LOG_FILE,"J= "+ j + "    Kvp Key: " + kvp.Key[i] +"        Kvp value: " + kvp.Value[j]);

                    }
                }

                if (!this.Batch.TryAppendDetailSet(documentID, kvp.Key, kvp.Value, false, out error))
                {
                    WriteLogEntry(LOG_ERRORS, LOG_FILE, "TryAppendDetailSet Error at DocID: " + documentID + ", Error: " + error.Message + ", kvp.Key.Length = " + kvp.Key.Length.ToString());
                }
            }
```

What would be nice is if I could print out to my log only the key and value that gets passed on the fly.

like this, except this doesnt work, I beleive it puts out something like System.String in my logs.

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string[], string[]> kvp in orderedList)
            {
            WriteLogEntry(LOG_ERRORS, LOG_FILE, "Key: " + kvp.Key.ToString() + "Value: " + kvp.Value.ToString());

                if (!this.Batch.TryAppendDetailSet(documentID, kvp.Key, kvp.Value, false, out error))
                {
                    WriteLogEntry(LOG_ERRORS, LOG_FILE, "TryAppendDetailSet Error at DocID: " + documentID + ", Error: " + error.Message + ", kvp.Key.Length = " + kvp.Key.Length.ToString());
                }
```

Also what is this type of KVP called? I have had a hard time googleing it? a KVP with two arrays sounds to me like a multidimensional KVP.

Also the format for the TryAppendDetailSet(string,string[],object[],bool,error)
                }

Comment: A KVP using string arrays is still just a KVP. However, it does look like an abuse just to pair up two sets of data here. Either way, it's not clear what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: I just want to know exactly what is getting passed into the TryAppendDetailSet function. I believe that I am writing everything out to the log with the nested for loops. 

Its just I am not sure how the for each is working with regard to this KVP with two arrays. I assume that it is iterating through the KVPs in the same way my nested for loop is putting them into my log.

I think It would be better to output the key and value as they are about to get passed into the function be sure my understanding is correct.

Comment: Well `kvp.Key` is an array of strings, as is `kvp.Value`. As for what it's doing with it, who knows - we don't have the code to see that.

Comment: Its not a matter of what its doing with it, its a matter of what getting passed. I have been struggling trying to find an easy way to output the kvp.Key and kvp.Value values to a log. To do this i thought I could do something like `myStringKey = kvp.key;` `myStringvalue = kvp.Value` for the current iteration and just output my new strings to a file. However `WriteLogEntry(LOG_ERRORS, LOG_FILE, "Key: " + kvp.Key.ToString() + "Value: " + kvp.Value.ToString());` gives me this in my log. Key: System.String[]Value: System.String[]

Comment: Like I said above, `kvp.Key` is *an array of strings*, do you understand that?

Comment: Yes, I just am not sure how my for each statement steps through the KVP, the only way I can be sure then is to output each kvp.Key and kvp.Value that it iterates through to string in a log. Which is why I need to figure out how I can extract the current kvp.key and kvp.value values that it is currently on.

Comment: OK, I give up. You keep changing what you're asking for and it's highly unclear what you mean. Good luck finding an answer :)

Comment: Sorry for the frustration, I am not the best programmer. I feel like there is some fundamentals I am missing. I think I see what your saying now, I am passing arrays into the function, not one value, so I couldnt output the value in this way. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

The `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` type is used mainly for entries in a `Dictionary`. As such, the intent is that the `Key` field is generally something you would use for a Dictionary lookup... think `int` or `string`. It is unusual to see the `KeyValuePair` type used in this way... not unheard of, but not very common either.

With the advent of Tuples, it's even less common. Before we had easy Tuples, KeyValuePair was sometimes appropriated to take the place of a two-member Pair tuple. If you're using a recent version of .Net, you can add the System.ValueTuple package and use code more like this:

```
var orderedList = new List<(string[], string[])>();
```

That gives you an ordered list of Tuples, where both items in the Tuple are string arrays. You might also consider a jagged array:

```
 var orderedList = new List<string[2][]>();
```

or since it seems the number of entries is always the same, a multi-dimensional array:

```
var orderedList = new List<string[,]>();
```

Where the first dimension when adding array items to that list is always 2.